# I want to extract only the numbers in this part of the URL.[Regular expressions]

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I want to extract this part. But I couldn't do it well. So I need you to tell me how to do it.

Example)
https://twitter.com/straw_berry0721/status/1596714080345415681?s=20&t=1nIbnSZ2YN2m5KZaOjO5GA

> 1596714080345415681

https://twitter.com/xxx/status/1595920708323999744

> 1595920708323999744

・my code (failed)

```
final result = _controller.text;

t = s.lastIndexOf('status'));
s.substring(t)
```

Comment: How about `\d`? `status\/(\d+)`

Comment: Do you use reg() ?

Comment: yes, you use RegExp()

Comment: I want your full code

Comment: url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.indexOf("?"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get this is parse it to `Uri` and use its `path` like this:

```
var str =
    "https://twitter.com/straw_berry0721/status/1596714080345415681?s=20&t=1nIbnSZ2YN2m5KZaOjO5GA";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(str);

print("id= ${uri.path.substring(uri.path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)}");//id= 1596714080345415681
```

or as @MendelG mentions in comment you can go with regex like this:

```
var reg = RegExp(r'status\/(\d+)');
var result = reg.firstMatch(str)?.group(1);
print("result = $result"); // result = 1596714080345415681
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply extract the last shown number from URLs like https://twitter.com/xxx/status/1595920708323999744 by splitting it to a `List<String>` then take the last element of it, like this:

```
String extractLastNumber(String url) {
return url.split("/").last;
}


final extractedNumber = extractLastNumber("https://twitter.com/xxx/status/1595920708323999744");

print(extractedNumber); // "1595920708323999744"
print("status: $extractedNumber"); // "status: 1595920708323999744"
```

Note: this will return the number as `String`, if you want to get it as an `int` number you could use the `int.tryParse()` method like this:

```
print(int.tryParse(extractedNumber)); // 1595920708323999744
```